# Removing unwanted header and bottom part of sql result

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, stored-procedures

I am executing a sql script in unix by saying **sqlplus -L cimkroger/cimkroger@orcl @procdemo.sql > demo.txt** .It generates proper result in **demo.txt** file. But i don't want connected,SQL*Plus,Disconneted,...an so on text in demo.txt part. Is there anyway in sql query by which i can avoid this.Below is the conent of demo.txt file.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on Tue Jun 25 14:03:26 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

136209
136220
136152
136248
136196
136227
136163
136234
136174
136241
136185
135910

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [the `-s` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#sthref225) to invoke [silent mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_seven.htm#i1043544):

```
sqlplus -S -L cimkroger/cimkroger@orcl @procdemo.sql > demo.txt
```

The command line options are shown [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374).